# Least Squares Triangulation in R

Tags: r, triangulation, least-squares

Which are the coordinates of an unknown point if they are given observations of the distances of 3 points with known coordinates?

eg:

```
x = c(30.0,10.0,50.0)
y = c(150.0,120.0,50.0)
distance = c("125.0 ± 0.5","133.5 ± 0.2","98.6 ± 0.2")
df = data.frame(x, y, distance)
```

Is it possible to use R to calculate the coordinates of the unknown point using least squares with (a) indirect observations method and (b) condition equations?

How data in the form of "125.0 ± 0.5" can be imported in R?

Comment: Data of the form "125.0 ± 0.5" would be imported in 'character' mode. You can then break it up with `strsplit` and coerce the results to 'numeric'. You should also clarify what is actually desired. What is "the unknown point"? Are those "hard" edges to the implied upper and lower radii around centers or is there a statistical aspect to these uncertainty bounds? Are the radii associated in order with the centers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a start.  I think there are ways to linearalize the equations, thus simplifying the procedure.  But, this just takes the obvious approach of finding the intersection of the three circles, and uses `nlm` to minimize the squares.  I don't deal with the errors at all here.

```
## Your data
x = c(30.0,10.0,50.0)
y = c(150.0,120.0,50.0)
## distance = c("125.0 ± 0.5","133.5 ± 0.2","98.6 ± 0.2")
dists <- c(125, 133.5, 98.6)  # simplified

## Minimize this function:
## x: guesstimates
## centers: fixed points (x, y)
## b: distances
f <- function(x, centers, b) {
    sqrt(sum((sqrt(colSums((x - centers)^2)) - b)^2))
}

## Get estimate: initial guess of c(100, 100)
centers <- matrix(c(x, y), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
res <- nlm(f, c(100, 100), centers=centers, b=dists)

## Lets visualize to see if it worked
circle <- function(x, y, d, col='black') {
    theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=100)
    data.frame(x=d*cos(theta)+x, y=d*sin(theta)+y, col, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}
cols <- colorRampPalette(c('blue', 'red'))(3)
circs <- Map(circle, x, y, dists, cols)
ps <- do.call(rbind, circs)
plot(ps[1:2], type='n')
grid()
abline(h=0, v=0)
points(x, y, col=cols, pch=16, cex=2)
for (i in circs) points(i[1:2], col=i$col, type='l')

## Add the estimated point
points(x=res$estimate[1], y=res$estimate[2], 
       col='firebrick', pch=8, cex=2)
```

[image]